# Is there any canon source for Sora no Otoshimono?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

In the anime, it says that Ikaros Apollon can destroy a country several times throughout the manga. Her shield is strong enough to contain the blast. Hephaestus, her cannon was created to be an anti-weapon and one slight mistake could lead to the destruction of the planet.

Is there any canon source that shows if this is true because the anime sometimes contradicts itself?

Comment: The manga, duh.